# How to identify multiple Google Forms feeding one Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Sheet with many different "sheet tabs" across the bottom.  Several of them are tied to a Google Form, so that when that form is populated the entries show on that "tab".

I'm trying to also inject those entries into a MySQL database.  I have gotten this to work successfully using a single Google Sheet/Form pairing using a Google Apps Script tied to the Sheet, which listens for onFormSubmit.  That code follows:

```
// These are the Database connections values
var user = 'dbUsername';
var userPwd = 'dbPassword';
var db = 'databaseName';

var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.0:3306/' + db;

/**
 * @param {Object} e The event parameter for form submission to a spreadsheet;
 *     see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events
 */
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  console.log(e);
  var color = e.namedValues['Color1'][0]; // these names ('Color', 'Number') come from the Form's Question 
  var number = e.namedValues['Number1'][0];
  writeColor(color, number);
}

/**
 * Write one row of data to a table.
 */
function writeColor(color, number) {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd); // this connects to the database

  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO test_google_forms '
      + '(`color`, `number`) values (?, ?)');
  stmt.setString(1, color);
  stmt.setString(2, number);
  stmt.execute(); // this performs the SQL that was "prepared" in the previous 3 lines
}
```

However it appears Google triggers that function whenever ANY of the attached Forms is submit.  So if I have two Forms feeding different tabs of the same Sheet, it executes this code regardless of which Form was submit (or which tab it was writing to).

Further, I don't see any information in the passed event object about which form it came from (or tab it was writing to), so I don't know how I can triage these responses to go to the correct MySQL tables.

Is there some way I can filter these calls, or do I NEED to break up my Sheet into 1-tab-per-Sheet to avoid this conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get to the form based on the sheet name:

```
function getFormNameBySheetName(e) {
  //assume that this function is installable onEdit trigger handler
  const fObj = {'Sheet1Name':'Form1Name',
                'Sheet2Name':'Form2Name'
     }; // You can build this form you personal knowledge of which form is to which sheet
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const name = sh.getName();
  if(!fObj.hasOwnProperty(name)) return;
  const formname = fObj[name];
  return formname;
}
```

[onFormSubmit trigger event obj](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events?hl=en#form-submit)